# Counting rows in the table which have 1 or more missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please advise how to find the number of rows in the table which have 1 or more missing values? The missing values are represented in my table by `question marks = '?'`. The table has `15 columns and ~50k rows`. When I run the following query for some of the columns I can receive some results:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name ='?'
```

However I have also columns which bring me result: `"Error converting data type varchar to float"`

I would like to be able to find the number of rows in the table which have 1 or more missing values using 1 query/not run separately for each column.

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: Clearly, the values for numeric columns are not `'?'`.  You might provide sample data and desired results for your question.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "1 or more missing values"?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over all the columns in the table to check for missing values? Also, what type can the columns be?

Comment: I need to count all rows (out of 50k rows) which contain at least one column (15 columns) with missing value which is ='?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Count(*)
From   mySchema.myTable
Where  Cast(Col1 As NVarChar(128)) +
       Cast(Col2 As NVarChar(128)) +
       Cast(Coln As NVarChar(128)) Like '%?%'
```

It's ugly and **WILL** be slow *and* you may need to modify the Casts accordingly, but should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Rachel. This works perfectly. Thank you ALL for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any column:

```
select count(*)
from table_name
where column_name is null or cast(column_name as varchar(255)) = '?';
```

Comment: This is great Gordon, is it possible to run your query for all 15 columns at once. I would like to count all rows (out of 50k rows) which contain at least one column (15 columns) with missing value which is ='?'

Comment: This answer will only work for columns which can contain the valie'?' - i.e. text columns. Numeric, date etc will not work.

Comment: Thank you Peter, is there a solution to count all rows which contain at least one column with missing value for both numeric and text columns.

Comment: @PeterSmith . . . This will work for all columns.  Obviously, a numeric column will fail the `'?"` test, because a numeric column cannot contain `?`.  That is why there is also a test for `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:
Just set table name and it will get all columns
Also you can give value_to_match like '?' in your case or any other if you want.

```
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(max) = 'table_name'
DECLARE @value_to_match nvarchar(max) = '1'
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @Condition nvarchar(max) = ' OR ' -- 1 OR when you want to count row if any column has that value -- 2 when you want all all columns to have same value

SELECT @query = @query + ' cast(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' as nvarchar(500)) = ''' + @value_to_match + '''' + @Condition FROM informatioN_schema.columns WHERE table_name = @table_name
if @@rowcount = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Table doesn''t Exists'
    RETURN
END
SELECT @query = LEFT(@query,LEN(@query)-3)
PRINT ('select count(9) FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE ' + @query)
EXEC ('select count(9) FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE ' + @query)
```

Comment: Thank you Parth, After I successfully run the first 4 statements (declare), I tried to run the rest of them but I received the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@query".